# Multiple imports of the same file name

Tags: python, plugins, import, system

I am trying to create a plugin system and I have a function that imports all the modules into an array.

Layout of Plugins:

> pluginsDir/
>
> pluginsDir/chat
>
> pluginsDir/chat/main.py

And this is the function that finds and imports the plugins:

```
if os.path.exists(pluginsDir):
    for path, dirArray, fileArray in os.walk(pluginsDir):
        for fileName in fileArray:
            if fileName == "main.py":
            sys.path.append(path)
            try:
                plugins.append(__import__("main"))
            except:
                print 'Could not import plugin, "'+path+'": plugin contains errors or is not a real plugin.'
```

This is fine if I only have one plugin but when I have multiple plugins it keeps importing the first plugin it detects.

Layout of Plugins:

> pluginsDir/
>
> pluginsDir/chat
>
> pluginsDir/chat/main.py
>
> pluginsDir/build
>
> pluginsDir/build/main.py

I've tried to add`sys.path.remove(path)`after my try statement, but it doesn't remove the path after I have already imported the module.

What can I do to import my plugins correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.path.append(path)` will attach the plugin folder to the **end** of `sys.path`.  Since Python searches folders in `sys.path` from front to back, appending additional paths to the end of the list will not be found because any main.py modules in folder specified earlier in `sys.path` will essentially hide modules in folders at the end of the list.  Instead, you could use `sys.path.insert(0, path)` to add new paths to the front of the list.

You should look at [Python packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for a way to better structure the plugins.

```
plugindir/
    __init__.py
    plugin1/
        __init__.py
    plugin2/
        __init__.py
```

With Python packages, the loop in your script can be easily implemented with:

```
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_plugindir)
for folder in dirArray:
    __import__(folder)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Python module system is just a very cool way to handle namespaces. Importing several modules with the same name to your current namespace will clutter it.

No need to traverse the pluginsDir and import each file, Python will do that for you (from pluginsDir import *). If main.py does only initialization stuf you can move the code to `pluginsDir/chat/__init__.py`.

Import pluginsDir refering to your plugins like 'pluginsDir.chat' is considered better pratice.

Comment: I need to do this with my method because the plugins are dynamic, not static, so if a plugin is added, my script won't detect it with this method.

Comment: You can use builtin function reload. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop is not indented, I don't see why your code runs at all. Fixing the indentation might fix the problem.

Comment: That's because I modified my code to be more readable on here but I ended up taking away some indentation.